# ¿Como usar condicionales en la respuesta de un get de Axios en Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, condiciones, axios

estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de implementar un condicional con la respuesta de un get de Axios en Vue.js.

He intentado con la sintaxis normal de JS pero da error.

```
mounted () {
        axios
          .get('http://localhost:8080/sitio/rest/marcaColor/marcaColores')
          .then(response => (
                                if(response.data.exito == true){
                                    this.marcaColores = response.data.objetoRespuesta;
                                }else{
                                    this.marcaColores = [];
                                }

                            )
               )
      }
```

El error que me da es

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'if'

¿Como puedo usar condicionales en esa parte del código?

Comment: Saludos MrCode, buen día, por curiosidad ¿has visto la documentación https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema ?

Comment: @fredyfx si pero con exito no me refiero al HTTP status si no al resultado de las operaciones que hace el Web Service. Puede darme un 200 y aun así exito ser falso.

Comment: ¿Por qué usas "(" luego de la flecha, no se supone que va una llave "{" ? Por otro lado, dale un console.log(response) para que veas el objeto que te retorna y confirmes que la variable "exito" sea existente

Comment: Me he basado en este tutorial y alli usan esa sintaxis. https://es.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

Comment: porque es una expresión de 1 sola línea... Creo que te caerían bien unas clases de javascript http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javascriptya/index.php?inicio=80 a partir de la página que se ve, encuentras las "novedades". buena suerte

Comment: JavaScript se, lo que no sabia es que las sentencias de una linea se pueden meter entre parentesis. De todas formas sigue sin funcionar con llaves. Siempre va al else a pasar de que `response.data.exito` es `true`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100557/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-mrcode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisa los comentarios dentro del código, contiene la explicación.

```
mounted () {
     axios
          .get('http://localhost:8080/sitio/rest/marcaColor/marcaColores')
          .then(response => { //Aqui va primera llave de apertura
            // if(response.exito) da error porque "exito" se encuentra dentro de response.data
            //utiliza 3 signos igual para equivalencias de tipo de variable
            if (response.data.exito === true) { 
              this.marcaColores = response.data.objetoRespuesta;
            } else {
              this.marcaColores = [];
            }

          }) //aquí va la segunda llave de cierre y el paréntesis del .then(
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Coloco el siguiente script como ejemplo, tratando sirva como guía:

- Primero lo que deberías validar es el `status` de tu llamada AJAX, es decir verificar que estado esta devolviendo por ejemplo:

> Un status **200** indica que la llamada o petición ha resultado satisfactoria

En este caso a nivel de código lo encuentras si haces:

```
console.log(response)
```

Con un resultado como este:

```
[native code] },
    status: 200,
    statusText: "",
    timeout: 0,
    UNSENT: 0,
    upload: [object XMLHttpRequestUpload] { ... },
    withCredentials: false
  },
  status: 200,
  statusText: ""
}
```

Entonces lo podemos validar de este modo:

```
axios.get('url-a-consultar')
     .then((response) => {
  if(response.status === 200) {
    console.log(response.data)
  }else{
    console.log(0)
  }
})
```

hacer uso de `console.log(response.data)` devolverá todo el oncjunto de datos de la consulta que haces a una determinada URL.

Ya si por ejemplo buscas obtener un solo valor de esa respuesta, al ser un conjunto de datos, solo basta que indiques la posición deseada así:

```
console.log(response.data[0])
```